# Нужен веб-сервис менеджер проектов, посоветуйте?

Tags: менеджмент

Что-нибудь поскромнее, чем, например, redmine (в смысле по функционалу). В частности нужен трекер ошибок, требований. Очень понравилась подобная система на гитхабе, как раз то, что нужно, однако мне **не** нужна еще и VCS. Важно, чтобы до менеджера было легко добраться любому участнику проекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)

Удобно использовать, если Вы работаете по Scrum/Agile

Answer (score -1):

Как на счет [ClickUp](https://clickup.com/)?

Отличный функционал за приемлемые деньги